# Where should one place the meta tags to embed the Facebook Comments plugin?

Tags: facebook, comments, embed, meta-tags, facebook-comments

I would like to embed the Facebook Comments plugin on my site.
Where should I place the meta tags in order to add moderators for the comment box?

I've tried merging the tags with the div and placing it between the div like this, but with no results:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com meta property="fb:admins" content="{12345678901234567890}"/" data-num-posts="1" data-width="600"></div>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com <meta property="fb:admins" content="{12345678901234567890}"/>" data-num-posts="1" data-width="600"></div>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com"  data-num-posts="1" data-width="600"><meta property="fb:admins" content="{12345678901234567890}"/></div>
```

The comment box does work without the meta tags, though without the moderator support of course.
If it matters, my site is published on [webs.com](https://www.webs.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meta does not go in the plug-in code.  The meta tags go into the HTML of the site located at the data-href's URL. It is placed in the page's `<HEAD>` section.